# Inventory Management where main list highlights items checked out/ in

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am working on an inventory management list where barcodes are scanned out and scanned back in.  My sheet is attached to forms.  I have set the item sku# on the main inventory list to highlight red when checked out and pull the location of the item from the checked out list over to the inventory sheet (column L), but I am struggling to make it show when an item is checked back in. Ideally I would like the item sku# to highlight red as shown when it is checked out and have the location show in yellow when checked out, but I need the item sku# to go back to no color when checked in and remove the item location from the main inventory list when checked in.  I attempted using a formula I found on the status tab, but it is not showing when items are scanned multiple times.  Is there a way to code this so that it does it with each scan in/out?  I have tried using several formulas, but I am not all that great with excel.  any help is greatly[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CVibr5ltFg-v8w2rl6TPdGSpul8SMTnG3jPZOcf5Di4/edit#gid=0) appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your spreadsheet requires access permission; would you please change this allow access by anyone (if it contains private information, remove it and substitute dummy transactions). It seems that you have been able to have the SKU display in RED when scanned out; why not apply the same logic to making the location display in yellow. As " it is not showing when items are scanned multiple times", would you explain EXACTLY what this means and why it would be a problem. Lastly, you mention Excel but have tagged Google Sheets -which are you using for this task?

Comment: sorry about that!  Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mKgfcuNZ6naXhPnUCu3uKOTVrGERbLJWSO5MNyTUFZ4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tried to use the same logic however I get an error.  Once an item is checked out, it shows, but once I scan in I cannot get it to do the same function because it is being overridden by my original formula.  I was also having an issue with the multiple scan function.  It will only show when the sku is initially scanned, but will not take into account multiple scans.  These items will be checked out and checked in regularly so it will need to be able to reach multiple scans.

Comment: Is this dummy data? It looks remarkably detailed and includes data that I would regards as confidential??

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, EVERY item of inventory has its own SKU? Granted it is a while since I worked in the industry, but doesn't an SKU typically describe the product, rather than each and every unit of the product. In any event, would you explain how the system is attached to forms, and under what circumstances would a product be scanned "back in"?

Comment: This is inventory for a staging company so all of the data is vital for our use.  we are creating this inventory list to check items out to specific stages (locations) and then will be checking them back in as we get items back once the home sells.  Each item requires its own sku for scanning.  I have them linked to a check out/ check in form.  We are using the scan to web app that is linked to the form to check an item out and we have a separate for for checking in.

Comment: Pls edit your question. You have put too much into comments, while all the info must stay in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an inventory sheet showing relevant standing data including the unique SKU; you also want to record the location of each item, and format the SKU and Location fields depending on the status of the item. Issues In and Out are recorded on Google Forms, and details of those responses are included on other sheets in the same spreadsheet.

**Use this formula in cell L3 on "INVENTORY"**

`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(J3:J,query({query({CHECKEDIN!A2:D},"select  Col1, Col4,'IN' where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc LABEL 'IN' '' ");query({CHECKEDOUT!A2:E}," select Col1,Col4, Col5 where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc ")},"Select Col2, Col3 order by Col1 desc"),2,0),""))`

**Conditional formatting - Column L (Location)**

- Custom formula
- `=NOT(or(J3="IN",len(J3)=0))`

**Conditional; formatting = Column K (SKU)**

- repeat the same custom formula but chnage the background colour to suit.

**Logic**

- Combine the records of CheckedOUT and CheckedIN
- Add a column to "CheckedIN" so that it has the same number of columns as Checked Out
- Sort the results by date desc
- `VLOOKUP` the SKU in the results of the query and return the location.

---

**Sample checkedIN**
Note: the transaction highlighted in Yellow.

[image: IN]

---

**Sample checkedOUT**
Note: the extra transaction highlighted in Yellow

[image: Out]

---

**Inventory (conditional formatted)**
[image: Inventory]

Comment: I cant thank you enough! I think this is exactly what I need. I am attempting it, but I am getting an error. My data is not translating like yours did. I know according to the formula it should be listed as 'in". Any ideas?  The conditional formatting is not pulling properly.  Also, do I need to keep my original conditional format on the SKU column like I had and should I keep my same vlookup on the location column

Comment: Formula is `=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(N3:N,query({query({'CHECKED IN'!A2:D},"select Col1, Col4,'IN' where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc LABEL 'IN' '' ");query({'CHECKED OUT'!A2:E}," select Col1,Col4, Col5 where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc ")},"Select Col2, Col3 order by Col1 desc"),2,0),""))`. 3 differences 1)`CHECKED IN` has space in the sheet name; 2) ditto `CHECKED OUT`; 3) the CheckedOut query is combined with the CheckIn query - this is done by separating them with a `;` (semi-colon) - this is the specific section: `;query({'CHECKED OUT'`(you have a comma here).

Comment: Conditional formatting: "Project Use"-the first row of the range must align with the custom formula. You had P1:P50000+, but the custom formula references row#3. Suggest you alter the range to be P3:P50000+.

Comment: It looks like this is working!  You are amazing.  I cant thank you enough.

Comment: Conditional formatting: "SKU" - 1) change the range to start at row #3 (as above). 2) the custom formula needs to reference the "Project Use" column

Comment: For your spreadsheet, the custom formula for both "SKU" and "Project use" is `=NOT(or(P3="IN",len(P3)=0))`. That is, it is effective if the value = "IN" OR if the cell is empty (length=zero). And the "NOT" that applies to all of that ensures that the desired format only applies to cells other than "IN" or empty.

Comment: Ok.  I will try that again.  It was highlighting the "IN" cells, but not the others initially.  I was testing it out with conditional formatting to the words in the cells.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then you might consider “accepting” it.

Comment: Accepted!  Thank you again.  This worked perfectly.